# Selecting one of two nodes in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

all Cypher masters!

I can't figure out how to query all `B` nodes while choosing either `B1` or `B2` and `B4` or `B5`. There is no constraint on which of them, only that one is chosen. As in the image, there's a relation (B1,B2) and (B4,B5).

In other words - I want to `MATCH` all nodes of type `B` connected to some node with type `A`, but excluding either `B1` or `B2` and `B4` or `B5` (using the relation between them) in the result. The nodes of type `B` can only be pairwise connected - that is, no (B1,B2), (B2,B3) will exists simultaneously. Although, there can be more than one pair as the image shows.

Any ideas are more than welcome!

[image]

Comment: Can you explain this more? What are your expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify. Hope it's enough, otherwise I'll try to explain more

Comment: So if there exists a relationship between the connected :B nodes, you only want to select one of those connected nodes? What if multiple nodes are connected (B1, B2, B3), would you want only one of that set?

Comment: That's a great question. They'll be at most pairwise connected (B1, B2), (B3, B4). I did forget that. I'll update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a simple additional condition:

```
MATCH (A:A)--(B:B)
OPTIONAL MATCH (B)--(BT:B)--(A) 
WITH B WHERE BT IS NULL OR id(B) > id(BT)
RETURN B
```

Comment: Works flawless! Although, one little question - if there are no B's connected to one another, can I just return all B's somehow?

Comment: Yes, in that case query return all B.

Comment: Cause I'm getting zero B's. Not really sure why

Comment: @RikardOlsson I think that an example of data is needed for discussion - in the form of a cypher-query for adding.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I refer back to my first comment, first two words including exclamation mark. Thank you, man!

Answer (score 0):

So for this, it will be faster to use APOC Procedures, as there are some helpful collection functions, and a procedure we'll want to easily get the relationships that exist between a group of nodes.

The idea here is that we'll match to the connected :B nodes, use the `cover()` procedure to get all relationships among these nodes, collect those relationships and from those take one of the nodes for those relationships (we'll use the startnode here), and then we'll just subtract those chosen nodes from our list leaving us with the :B nodes we want:

```
MATCH (a:A)--(b:B)
WITH collect(b) as bNodes
CALL apoc.algo.cover(bNodes) YIELD rel
WITH bNodes, [r in collect(rel) | startNode(r)] as toRemove
RETURN apoc.coll.subtract(bNodes, toRemove) as nodes
```

If you don't have (or don't want to use) APOC, here's a Cypher-only version:

```
MATCH (a:A)--(b:B)
WITH collect(b) as bNodes
UNWIND bNodes as b
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)-[r]-(other)
WHERE other IN bNodes
WITH bNodes, collect(DISTINCT startNode(r)) as toRemove
RETURN [b in bNodes WHERE NOT b in toRemove] as nodes
```

Comment: This would probably work fantastic if it weren't for that the edges are bi-directional. Or I may use it incorrectly. toRemove is equal bNodes.. :(

Comment: Do you mean that you always have two relationships between the same two nodes instead of just one (or at least that it CAN be 2 rels instead of 1)? Is there any chance you can refactor that away, or is this a situation where the reciprocal relationship is significant?

Comment: Yes exactly, there are always two relationships between the same two nodes and I cannot remove one of them, unfortunately. I guess now that's the big issue here...